# Websocket server which to choose?

Tags: php, mysql, websocket, memcached

I am developing a big PHP application in ZF2, and I need real-time interaction in this app, so websocket are my choose.
I have PHP, Mysql, Memcached. I need a websocket server. What would be the best choise.
Requiments of my websocket server:

- support mysql, memcached and maybe gearman
- Support https connections, very important
- optionally support IE (but this is not important if loose benefits)
- scalable

**My problem is choosing from a PHP (wrench) websocket server or a based Node.js(socket.io) server.
Which should I choose?**

If I use the PHP one I can use PHP code and ZF2 function, so easy to develop, but I do not have non-html5 browser support (do I have ssl support here?)

If I use socket.io I have all browser support and fallback, but here I need to re-write all function (in js) to work with mysql, memcached and so on...

Comment: OK, thanks yo those users, that down votes without a reason and without a comment. Who are you? congratulation, this is developers community? is this a community?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WaterSpout Server claims to offer WebSocket or Long-Polling connections:
https://github.com/chrisnetonline/WaterSpout-Server

So this may be a solution that works in all browsers.

All solutions are scalable. The questions are really; how soon do you want to have to start thinking about scaling? When do you want to scale vertically and add additional resource to your server? When do you want to add another server (scale horizontally) and deal with synchronisation connection and state information between those servers? IMHO you'll be doing this sooner with a PHP solution.

If you mainly want to write code in PHP and you would prefer to keep things simple then I'd recommend you use a [hosted realtime service](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#hosted-services) as part of your application stack.

Some relevant posts (*which I wrote*):

- [Understanding Realtime PHP Apps](http://webandphp.com/UnderstandingRealtimePHPApps-166085)
- [Building Realtime Web Apps with PHP](http://webandphp.com/BuildingRealtimeWebAppswithPHP-166928)

Comment: Thank you. Our app is most for limited users set ( clients). So scale will be the last of our problems for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Node.js, because PHP is not the best solution for applications, which have to stay in memory for a long time (PHP leaks memory).

http://software-gunslinger.tumblr.com/post/47131406821/php-is-meant-to-die

I'm sure there are lots of reusable Node modules for you not to reinvent a bycicle.

Of course, if it works for you, you can use some PHP-powered daemon and restart it once in a while to control it's stability to some extent.